# Generating custom errors for jquery.ajax()

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Lets assume that i have the following method in my httphandler (.ashx):

```
private void Foo()
{
    try
    {
        throw new Exception("blah");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(
            serializer.Serialize(new AjaxError(e)));
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class AjaxError
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string InnerException { get; set; }
    public string StackTrace { get; set; }

    public AjaxError(Exception e)
    {
        if (e != null)
        {
            this.Message = e.Message;
            this.StackTrace = e.StackTrace;
            this.InnerException = e.InnerException != null ? 
                e.InnerException.Message : null;


            HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusDescription = "CustomError";
        }

    }
}
```

When i make an `$.ajax()` call to the method, I will end up in the `success` callback, regardless if something goes wrong back-end and I end up in the `catch` block.

I've extended the ajax method a bit to normalise the error handling, so regardless if it's a "jquery" error (parse error etc) or my custom error, i will end up in the error callback.

Now, what I would like to know is, should i add something like

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 500;
```

to end up in jQuerys error handler, or should i handle my

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusDescription = "CustomError";
```

on the jqXHR object, and assume its an error when its there?

Let me know if something is unclear.

Comment: you should send on of the error codes in 4xx or 5xx series, to make it fall in the error callback, list of HTTP codes http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: @Furqan Which one would you suggest? I've already seen the list, but, imo, none of them matched my needs. I mean, could you really classify my custom error as an "internal server error" for example?

Comment: If none of them even matches your code, you can send your own code like 450, it shall just make your call fall in the error handler and there you can check for your custom code and process appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to at least use the status code because that way your $.ajax can implement the fail function like this:

```
$.ajax({...})
    .fail(function(xhr) {
        console.log(xhr.statusText); // the status text
        console.log(xhr.statusCode); // the status code
    });
```

If you want to just send the text straight to the user can you use statusText.  You also, if you want, can do different status codes for different errors (even if the status codes aren't conventional) like this:

```
$.ajax({...})
    .fail(function(xhr) {
        switch(xhr.statusCode) {
            case 401:
                // ... do something
                break;
            case 402:
                // ... do something
                break;
            case 403:
                // ... do something
                break;
        }
    });
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing :)